# GitLab Docker Registry Push Failed - Access Denied

Tags: docker, gitlab, docker-registry

I'm having trouble pushing to [GitLab Container Registry](https://gitlab.com/help/user/project/container_registry).

I can login successfully using my username and a personal access token but when I try to push the image to the registry, I get the following error:

```
$ docker push registry.gitlab.com/[groupname]/dockerfiles/nodemon

The push refers to a repository 
[registry.gitlab.com/[groupname]/dockerfiles/nodemon]
15d2ea6e1aeb: Preparing 
2260f979a949: Preparing 
f8e848bb8c20: Preparing 
740a5345706a: Preparing 
5bef08742407: Preparing 
denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

I assume the issue is not with authentication because when I run a `docker login registry.gitlab.com`, I get a `Login Succeeded` message.

Where is the problem?
How should I push my images to GitLab Container Registry?

Comment: Does a Git repository exist at `[groupname]/dockerfiles/nodemon` on GitLab?

Comment: @gregnr Yes. The Git repo is actually at `[groupname]/dockerfiles` but GitLab's [documentation states](https://gitlab.com/help/user/project/container_registry#build-and-push-images) that it supports up to 3 levels of image names so `[groupname]/dockerfiles/nodemon` is a valid name. Btw, using `[groupname]/dockerfiles` also causes the same issue.

Comment: Very strange issue. If you go to your GitLab repo (on browser) > Settings, is `Container Registry` enabled?

Comment: @gregnr Yes. it is enabled.

Comment: I believe I came across this issue for not having sufficient permissions, I would check if the user who runs the pipeline have the right permissions on that project and if you logged in with the user you are trying to push

Comment: @Sergiu I'm the owner of the group which contains the repo so I believe I should have the right permissions.

Answer (score 5):

I got it working by including `api` scope to my personal access token.

The docs states `The minimal scope needed is read_registry`. But that probably applies for read only access.

Reference: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/support-forum/issues/2370#note_44796408

Answer (score 2):

Had a similar issue, it was because of the url that was used for tagging and pushing the repo.

It should be

`docker push registry.gitlab.com/[account or group-name]/[reponame]/imagename`

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was really dumb, maybe even a gitlab bug :
I renamed the gitlab project after the creation of the container registry, so the container registry url was still with the old name ...
The project name under gitlab had the typo error corrected but not the registry link and it led to this error

Answer (score 2):

It was previously a correct answer to say that the personal access token needs to include the `api` permission, and several answers on this page say exactly that.

Recently, GitLab appear to have improved the granularity of their permission system. So if you want to push container images to the GitLab Docker registry, you can create a token merely with the `read_registry` and `write_registry` permissions. This is likely to be a lot safer than giving full permissions.

I have tested this successfully today.

Answer (score 0):

Enable the personal access token by adding `api` scope as per [this](https://gitlab.com/help/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.md#creating-a-personal-access-token) guidelines. After creating the token and username, use these credentials for logging into the Docker environment or pushing.

**Deploy tokens created under CI/CD setup is not sufficient for pushing the image to a Docker registry.**

Comment: It looks like GitLab have added new levels of permission granularity. To push an image, one can just have `read_registry` and `write_registry` - tested just now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
In my case, the issue was I had AutoDevOps enabled before, which seem to generate a deploy token automatically.
Now [deploy tokens](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/deploy_tokens/index.html#gitlab-deploy-token) are just API keys basically for deployment.
But GitLab has a special handling for `gitlab-deploy-token` which you can then access via `$CI_DEPLOY_USER` and `$CI_DEPLOY_PASSWORD` as a predefined variable.

However, I did not **double-check the default token**.
In my case, it only had `read_registry`, of course though, it also needs `write_registry` permissions.

If you do this, then you can follow [the official documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/container_registry/index.html#build-and-push-images-using-gitlab-cicd).

Alternatively, you can apparently also switch to `$CI_REGISTRY_USER` and `$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD`, which are ephemeral, however.